# TensorBoard - Viewing image summaries side-by-side?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

The network I'm working on in TensorFlow produces a pixel-wise labeling result. TensorBoard is very helpful for viewing the data during training, but if I simply add 3 `image_summary`s I get an layout of the images something like:

```
o1
o2
o3
l1
l2
l3
p1
p2
p3
```

(where `o#` is the original image, `l#` is the ground truth labels, and `p#` is the predicted labels). What I would prefer to see is a layout like:

```
o1 l1 p1
o2 l2 p2
o3 l3 p3
```

As this would make comparing the results much easier. Does TensorBoard provide any convenient way of achieving this? Or would taking all the images, mapping non-RGB ones RGB, and simply concatenating them to make one long image be the best solution? Thank you much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TensorBoard doesn't have solution for this at the moment; concatenating the images, like you proposed, would be a reasonable workaround.

I suggest filing a feature request on our Github :) the image dashboard is in need of some love, lots of people are using it and want improved layout and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can pin the images which you want to compare side by side.
Below is the tensorboard images which I am using in Colab Notebook.
[image: Tensorboard screenshot]